# Access form record source not found after search

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have developed a split form which uses the following record source:

`SELECT * FROM [CCG Complaints];`

The form works well and I have no problems with that side of things.

Users have two buttons: one to search, and one to show all records.

The problems arise when, after performing a search, I close the form and then reopen it again (in form view):

[image]

However, whenever I click `Show all` before closing the form, it opens successfully in form view with no errors.

Another feature is that, after receiving the error mentioned above, I am able to open the form in design view, and can then view it in form view without the error message - the error only occurs when the form is opened in form view in the first instance.

Why is this and what can I do to rectify it?

The code I use for the buttons is here:

```
Private Sub search_Click()
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strText As String
    If Len(Me.txtSearch.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Enter a search term.")
    Else
        strText = Me.txtSearch.Value
        strSearch = "SELECT* from [CCG Complaints] where [Ref no] Like ""*" & strText & "*"" or [lastName] Like ""*" & strText & "*"" Or CCG Like ""*" & strText & "*"" "
        Me.RecordSource = strSearch
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub showAll_Click()
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "SELECT * from [CCG Complaints]"
    Me.RecordSource = strSearch
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Is there a reason you don't use `[CCG Complaints]` as recordsource? -- 2. How do you filter (please add the code)? -- 3. If the form property `FilterOnLoad` is True, try setting it to False.

Comment: 1. Yes - the reason is because I have tried that and the error still persists. 2. Code added to question. 3. It is set to `No`, so I set it to `Yes` but the error is still thrown.  (I have set it back to `No`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to set the RecordSource to `[CCG Complaints]`, and not change it.

Instead use the `.Filter` properties, this is the usual way to implement a form filter:

```vb
Private Sub search_Click()
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strText As String
    If Len(Me.txtSearch.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Enter a search term.")
    Else
        strText = Me.txtSearch.Value
        strSearch = "[Ref no] Like ""*" & strText & "*"" or [lastName] Like ""*" & strText & "*"" Or CCG Like ""*" & strText & "*"" "
        Me.Filter = strSearch
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub showAll_Click()
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
End Sub
```

Comment: That did it - thanks!  Why was the error appearing in the first case?

Comment: I can't really tell - I'd have to try to reproduce it here, and don't really have the time. @SnookerFan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the recordsource, apply a filter to the existing records.

```
Me.filter =  "[Ref no] Like  ""*" & strText & "*"" or [lastName] Like ""*" & strText & "*"" Or CCG Like ""*" & strText & "*"" "
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Then Reset

```
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
```

Be aware that if your record set gets even slightly large, this wildcard searching on lots of fields will become very inefficient. You might want to look at a more robust search method. This http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html is a more complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - that is more like what I was looking to achieve.

Comment: Using the way detailed on this website, is there a way to change the record source within the same form?